# Error Run Time Error -2147024809 (80070057)

Tags: vba

I have a question for my macro in which I get an error when I run:

```
Run Time Error -2147024809 (80070057)
```

In line

```
If VBA.Len(Me.Controls("Textbox" & i).Value) > 0 Then
```

All code

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lWie As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheat1")

With wks
    lWie = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To 40
        If VBA.Len(Me.Controls("Textbox" & i).Value) > 0 Then
            lRow = lRow + 1
            .Cells(lWie + lRow, "A").Value = lWie + lRow - 1
            .Cells(lWie + lRow, "B").Value = .Range("P1").Value
            .Cells(lWie + lRow, "C").Value = .Range("R1").Value
            .Cells(lWie + lRow, "D").Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: That's ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. You could try separating that line into several separate lines to work out which specific bit is causing the error: concatenating "Textbox" & i, the Me.Controls call, the .Value on the result of that or the VBA.Len on the result of that.

Comment: What value has `i` when the code stops on error (move the cursor over the variable)? Are you sure that there are enough text boxes (from 1 to 40)?